# How to handle Nginx redirects efficiently

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I am merging 2 websites into 1, a.com and b.com.
I want to set up the redirect for a.com and b.com to go to a.com and all http to go to https.
I also have to mass redirect all the urls. Is the code below the best way to implement this?
Thank you.

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
 default "";
 /old/a-com-url /new/a-url;
 /old/b-com-url /new/b-url;
 ...
}

server {
 server_name a.com www.a.com b.com www.b.com;
 return 301 https://a.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name a.com www.a.com;
   if ($new_uri != "") {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ $new_uri permanent;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think what you have is good way to manage and express mass redirect urls. I would stay with this configuration

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Do you know if there is speed/performance difference if I move the map directive in between the 2 server directives?

Comment: Map can only be used at http directive level, you can't move it inside server. The only thing you can do is play with `map_hash_bucket_size` and `map_hash_max_size` to improve performance. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani thank you. I will go do some readings.